# Detecting when an integer is made up of only the same digit

Tags: java, integer, digit

I'm writing a Java program that will play a game. 
Basically you choose the no. of players and rounds, then the program shows you what every player should say, in order, considering the following rules:

-assuming the players are standing in a circle, they start counting one-by-one clockwise until someone reaches a number (larger than 10) made of only the same digit. For example 11, 22, 33, .. , 444 etc, then they start counting counter clockwise

E.g.: **P9**: 9; **P10**: 10; **P11**: 11; **P12**: 13; **P11**: 14 etc (P10 = Player 10)

-when the get to a number that is multiple of 7, contains 7 or the sum of the digits is 7, they say "Boltz"

E.g.: **P1**: 13; **P2**: Boltz (instead of 14); **P3**: 15; **P4** Boltz (16); **P5**: Boltz (17); **P6**:18 etc

I have the code in Java, but i can't seem to get the switching from clockwise turns to counterclockwise at numbers made up from only one digit

Can you please help me on SameDigits function? Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Boltz {
  private static Scanner keyboard;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int nPlayers = 0;
    int nRounds = 0;
    int currentPlayer = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int x = 0;
    boolean isSameDigit = true;

    System.out.print("Cati jucatori sunt? ");
    nPlayers = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Cate runde sunt? ");
    nRounds = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Jucatori: " + nPlayers + "; Runde: " + nRounds + "\n");

    for (x = 1; x <= nPlayers * nRounds; x++) {

        isSameDigit = SameDigits(currentPlayer);

        if (currentPlayer < nPlayers && isSameDigit == false) {
            currentPlayer++;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }

        if (currentPlayer > 1 && isSameDigit == true) {
            currentPlayer--;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = nPlayers;
        }

        sum = digitSum(x);

        if (x % 7 == 0 || String.valueOf(x).contains("7") || sum == 7) {
            System.out.println("P:" + currentPlayer + " Boltz");
        } else {
            System.out.println("P:" + currentPlayer + " " + x);
        }
    }
  }

  public static int digitSum(int num) {
    int suma = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        suma = suma + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return suma;
  }

  public static boolean SameDigits(int num) {
    int add = 0, add2 = 0;

    while (num > 0) {
        add = add + num % 10;
        add2 = add2 + add % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    if (add == add2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want `SameDigits` to return `true` if the number is all the same digits and `false` otherwise. Single-digit numbers should also return `true`. This should do it:

```
public static boolean SameDigits(int num) {
    if (num < 0) return false; // or something else?

    int onesDigit = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    while (num > 0) {
        if (onesDigit != num % 10) return false; // fail if digits differ
        num /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

P.S. You should conform to Java naming conventions and name your methods starting with a lower-case letter (`sameDigits` instead of `SameDigits`).

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like:

```
public static boolean sameDigits(int number) {
        //speical case
        if (number < 10)
            return false;
        String string = String.valueOf(number);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (string.replaceAll(String.valueOf(i), "").length() == 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you return false when `number < 10`?

Comment: I base it on the rule "assuming the players are standing in a circle, they start counting one-by-one clockwise until someone reaches a number (larger than 10) made of only the same digit. For example 11, 22, 33, .. , 444 etc, then they start counting counter clockwise" only. Besides it is quite easy to change ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Not the greatest method name, I guess.

Comment: Yep. I think it is a design issue... Another interesting fact is that the author wants to avoid the so well-known camelCase and call it SameDigits instead of sameDigits...

Comment: Cute idea, but it would be more efficient as: `return string.replaceAll(string.substring(0, 1), "").length() == 0;` instead of looping over all possible single digit strings.

Comment: @TedHopp, great idea!

Comment: Or `for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(0)) return false;`.

Comment: Or `return string.chars().distinct().count() == 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression.  This one checks whether a `String` consists of a single digit, followed by one or more repetitions of the same digit.

```
public static boolean sameDigits(int arg) {
    return Integer.toString(arg).matches("(\\d)\\1+");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be `"^(\\d)\\1+$"`?

Comment: @shalvah No, it doesn't need to be.  The `matches` method matches the whole string anyway - there's absolutely no need to add `^` and `$`.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I'm new to regex. What's the "\\1" part for?

Comment: Sequences like `\1` up to `\9` refer back to a match in parentheses.  So it means a repetition of whatever matched the content of the first set of parentheses - in this case, `\d`.